# Django static files not loading. Fix settings.py to load files on relative paths

Tags: css, django, static

I downloaded this template https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-resume and I am trying to use it in Django. I am having problems with static files, that is .css and .jpg.

My project is called Djangoresume and the app is resume. I copied the template files to my /home/kinkyboy/Djangoresume/resume/templates/resume (if you think the last resume folder is not the common way to do organize the project, please let me know):

```
> pwd
/home/kinkyboy/Djangoresume/resume/templates/resume
> tree -L1
.
├── css
├── gulpfile.js
├── img
├── js
├── index.html
├── scss
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   ├── js
│   ├── scss
│   └── vendor
└── vendor
```

Notice that I added the same static files to a new folder "static" to increase my chances of making Django work, but I'd rather not use it.

This is the IMO relevant part of settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
...
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/resume/templates/resume/static')
]
```

But I tried many different folders. I see that {% static %} uses STATIC_URL, and probably staticfiles will use STATICFILES_DIRS. BASE_DIR is where manage.py is, right?

I copy here a shorter version of the index.html in the repository:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Resume - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- no it does not work -->
    <link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Extra+Condensed:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vendor/devicons/css/devicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/resume.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body id="page-top">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top" id="sideNav">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
        <span class="d-block d-lg-none">Start Bootstrap</span>
        <span class="d-none d-lg-block">
          <img class="img-fluid img-profile rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2" src="img/profile.jpg" alt="">

<!--Try using static-->
<img class="img-fluid img-profile rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2" src="{% static 'img/profile.jpg' %}" alt="">

        </span>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#experience">Experience</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#education">Education</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#skills">Skills</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#interests">Interests</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#awards">Awards</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
    <script src="js/resume.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

This html work when opened directly in the browser, that is it is nicely formatted. It does not when used as template with Django. 
I did try to use {% static '' %} everywhere as follows:

```
<link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
src="{% static 'img/profile.jpg' %}"
```

and at the same time changing STATIC_URL. I even had a mixed success (some css got applied, some not) with some paths in STATIC_URL, now it is even hard to reproduce (I disabled the cache in the browser). I do get messages in terminal such as

```
Not Found: /js/resume.min.js
[01/Mar/2018 18:59:45] "GET /js/resume.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3599
```

I suppose my views.py, urls.py are ok because I can load index.html. Only the css and jpg do not load.

How to troubleshoot this? From the generated html in browser I do not understand what is loaded and what is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the static assets are not loading for you is Django is unable to find them in the static folder. Django looks for templates and static folder in the project and collects all of the assets while rendering them.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files).

You are correct in organizing your project structure for templates.

- It should be project/app/**templates**/***app***/***--files--***

***--files--*** is where your **index.html**  and other *.html files are kept.

But templates are used to keep only the HTML files which are rendered by the views. This folder is not used to store the static assets(namely CSS, JS, other framework files, etc).

Just like the templates folder, you need to have a similar structure for static assets.

- It should be project/app/**static**/***app***/***--files--***

***--files--*** here include all the CSS, JS, and other dependent static assets. This is the place where you keep the img, js, css, vendor, scss, etc. folders including any *.css or *.js files.

Below is how your static folder should look like.

```
static
├── resume
    ├── css...
    ├── img...
    ├── js...
    ├── scss...
    └── vendor...  
    ├── gulpfile.js
```

And below might be some useful code changes:

```
#settings.py
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
...
```

For *index.html* template,

```
{% load static %}  <!-- skip {% load staticfiles %} as it is not needed  anymore -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="{% static 'resume/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
...
etc
```

Here '*static*' in href="{% static .. %}" refers to the **static** folder in your **resume** app. To this, you append the assets you want to render by adding the path to those assets like I did above to use 'bootstrap.min.css'.

I hope some of your confusion is cleared. From what I gather, your views.py and urls.py files are configured correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought the urls given in the Django documentation were the suggested ones, not that static files cannot be served from the same folder as templates.